# Does providing an XML Schema collection for a Stored Procedure work with WCF-SQL Send Port?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, biztalk, biztalk-2016, xml-schema-collection

Consider the following simplified XML schema collection

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION CD.AcceptMessageSchema AS '
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit"
        xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"
        targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="AcceptMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MessagePayload" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="PatientIdentifiers">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="ID">                      
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

and the following Stored Procedure definition

```
create procedureSubmit.AcceptMessage_DEV @AcceptMessage xml(CD.AcceptMessageSchema) 
as
Insert into blah...
...stored proc guts go here...
```

You'll notice that the single paramter is defined associated to the Schema Collection. My assumption was that given the association to the SchemaCollection, you would be able to call the Stored Procedure by sending in something like the following:

```
<AcceptMessage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit" xmlns:biztalk="http://InteriorHealth.BizTalk.CDX.Schemas.SQLSubmit.AcceptMessage" xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MessagePayload>
    <![CDATA[somepayloaddata]]>
</MessagePayload>
<PatientIdentifiers>
    <ID OID="2.16.840.1.113883.4.50" Value="3454545" AssigningAuthorityName="Patient Health Number" />
    <ID OID="2.16.840.1.113883.3.277.1.73" Value="4545454" AssigningAuthorityName="Patient EMR Number" />
</PatientIdentifiers>
</AcceptMessage>
```

and it would work over a WCF-SQL send port.

The strange this is, if I call the stored procedure in SSMS:

```
EXEC Submit.AcceptMessage @AcceptMessage = '    <AcceptMessage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit" xmlns:biztalk="http://InteriorHealth.BizTalk.CDX.Schemas.SQLSubmit.AcceptMessage" xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MessagePayload>
    <![CDATA[somepayloaddata]]>
</MessagePayload>
<PatientIdentifiers>
    <ID OID="2.16.840.1.113883.4.50" Value="3454545" AssigningAuthorityName="Patient Health Number" />
    <ID OID="2.16.840.1.113883.3.277.1.73" Value="4545454" AssigningAuthorityName="Patient EMR Number" />
</PatientIdentifiers>
</AcceptMessage>';
```

it works just fine, but sending it over the wire via WCF-SQL I get the error:

`The start element with name "MessagePayload" and namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit" was unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.`

This is the same thing that would happen before I applied the XML Scheam collection and defined the stored proc like this:

```
create procedureSubmit.AcceptMessage_DEV
    @MessagePayload xml,
    @PatientIdentifiers xml
as
```

If I were to then send in a request like above, it would give the error:

`The start element with name "ID" and namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/Submit" was unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.`

Because it didn't know what to do with the `<ID>` elements inside the `<PatientIdentifiers>` element.

I previously was wrapping all parameter data in CDATA tags and it worked, but I wanted the added schema validation if it would work.

So does this mean that when calling WCF-SQL, I basically have to CDATA everything inside the parameter elements, or is there something I'm missing?

Also, this is a messaging-only solution, no orchestrations.

How can I send nested XML into a SQL Stored proc in order to parse it and insert the data into tables?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, I think a Table Value Parameter would be easier.

However, to answer what I think is your underlying question, you can pass an XML Type parameter either as CDATA or escaped Xml.  The WCF Schema Element Type will always be xs:string though.

You are generating a schema for the SP, correct?  You don't actually say.

Comment: 3 years later, I found my own old question when trying to find the answer once again. I want to ask what you mean by "generating a schema for the SP"? Let's say I did, which I have, what do I then do with the schema? It looks like I would have to alter in order for it to be aware of the elements nested past the first level of XML. IE: it's still going to barf if I include some `<ID>` elements in there